# Python - Inherit from a class in a submodule

Tags: python, python-3.x

In order to get a code easier to maintain, I wanted to split classes in different files, classified per role.
Everyting is placed into the same directory, with a **init**.py file to obtain a submodule.
Something like that :

```py
Resources
|- __init__.py
|- main_code.py
|- resources.py
|--- classes
     |- __init__.py
     |- solutions.py
     |- tests.py
```

But as in some classes of the tests.py, I inherit from other classes located in solutions.py, I've imported the solutions.py using :

```py
from . import solutions
```

Here is an example of my code in tests.py :

```py
from . import solutions

class snapshot(solutions.device):
    def __init__(self, d):
        solutions.device.__init__(self, d)
        self.ip = d
```

But doing that, I've got the following error:

```py
AttributeError: module 'solutions' has no attribute 'device'
```

I've also tried with :

```py
from resources.classes import solutions
```

But I've got the same result.

Thanks for your help,

EDIT

Here is the solutions.py :

```py
class device:

    def __init__(self, d: str, **kwargs):
        self.info = d
        username = kwargs.get("username", None)
        password = kwargs.get("password", None)
        action = kwargs.get("action", None)
        vault = kwargs.get("vault", None)
        self.init_connection(username, password, vault)
<--- ommitted for visibility --->
```

When everything was located into the same classes.py file, it worked perfectly.

Comment: Show us the solutions module. Also, try solutions.Device (capital D), which should lead from the convention of naming classes with a capital letter.

Comment: Just edited the question with the information - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do

```
from .solutions import device
```

in tests.py

Comment: Just tried your idea, but I've got another error :
from .solutions import Device
=> ImportError: cannot import name 'Device' from 'resources.classes.solutions' (./resources/classes/solutions.py)

Comment: If you are running directly the tests.py script it will raise this error. If you want to do that, make the import as "from solutions import Device". If you will call the script as a module (from another file), you should make "from .solutions import Device"

Comment: Btw, the name of your class is Device or device? If you renamed it, you must do it both in the class definition as in the import statement

Comment: I've made the change over all files. device is now Device everywhere.
Making your suggestion => File "./resources/classes/snapshots.py", line 6, in <module>
from .solutions import CXSwitch
ImportError: cannot import name 'CXSwitch' from 'resources.classes.solutions' (./resources/classes/solutions.py)
One additional thing is that tests.py is also called by another file (main_code.py), in order to get access to its classes.
from resources.classes import tests

Comment: OK, just found the issue : Circular dependencies...
Once I've fixed that (Splitted all common functions in several smaller files dedicated to specific roles), everything started to work...
Even using  "from classes import solutions" and calling the classes with "solutions.Device" inside the code.
Thanks again for your help.